# Regex to accept only numbers and a specific char

Tags: javascript, html, css, regex, expression

In javascript i have

```
var regex = /^\d+$/;
```

which accepts only numbers. How to remake it to accept numbers and the the character '-'

Answer (score 4):

You can use a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) for that:

```
var regex = /^[\d-]+$/;
```

However, this will also allow matches like `----`. If you only want to allow inputs like `123-456-789` but not `-123` or `123-` or `123--456`, then you can use something like

```
var regex = /^\d+(?:-\d+)*$/;
```

**Explanation:**

```
^     # Start of string.
\d+   # Match a number.
(?:   # Start of a non-capturing group that matches...
 -    #  a hyphen,
 \d+  #  followed by a number
)*    # ...any number of times, including zero.
$     # End of string
```